# What to use instead of respond_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails

From `rails 4.2`, `respond_with` and non-instance level `respond_to` have been moved to the `responders` gem. If I want to write a json response so I do not need the `responders` gem, this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28422845/respond-with-alternatives-in-rails-4-2-for-backbone) gives some alternatives. However, is there a rails 4.2 or rails 5 guide that deals the topic of responding to non-html in depth?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28422845/respond-with-alternatives-in-rails-4-2-for-backbone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this by binding the route to a format in the `routes.rb` file.

**EX.**

```
get 'my-json-route', to: 'controller#action', defaults: { format: :json }
```

[Here are the Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults)

Comment: This is useful but it does look like there is no specific rails guide on deals with this topic in depth.